# Optaplanner Shadow Variables

Tags: optaplanner

Recently learning Optaplanner constraint framework, but I can't understand the shadow variables, the documentation only has some simple descriptions, hope someone can help me, here is my code,thanks.

```
@Data
@PlanningEntity
public class CloudProcess {

private int requireCpuPower;

private int requireMemory;

private int requireNetworkBandwidth;

@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"computerRange"})
private CloudComputer cloudComputer;

}

@Data
@PlanningEntity
public class CloudComputer {
private int cpuPower;

private int memory;

private int networkBandwidth;

private int cost;

@InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "cloudComputer")
private List<CloudProcess> processList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@PlanningSolution
@Data
public class CloudBalance {

@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
private List<CloudProcess> processList;


@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
@ValueRangeProvider(id="computerRange")
private List<CloudComputer> computerList;

@PlanningScore
private HardSoftScore score;
}
```

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCodeRange(ArrayList.java:626) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.hashCode(ArrayList.java:613) ~[na:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudComputer.hashCode(CloudComputer.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at com.zxx.model.cloudBalancing.CloudProcess.hashCode(CloudProcess.java:7) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: What version of the documentation did you look at? The latest version explains shadow variables in detail: https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/shadow-variable/shadow-variable.html. Does that help? If not, can you narrow your question to be more specific?

Comment: The document version is 8.22.1 Final. I cannot understand the term shadow variable. In the cloud balancing example mentioned in the official website document, I cannot reproduce this example.

Comment: I have re-uploaded the relevant code in the question, but my running result is java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Comment: The code looks good. Please add the complete exception stack trace.

Comment: I have added a stack exception

Comment: I don't know why I get an error stack over flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation of the problem

The `java.lang.StackOverflowError` is caused by combination of two facts:

1. By introducing `@InverseRelationShadowVariable processList` on the `CloudComputer` you are creating a bi-directional relationship between `CloudComputer` and `CloudProcess`.
2. You are using Lombok [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data), which generates `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `toString()` implementations that use all the class fields by default.

That leads to an infinite loop because, for example, to compute `Process 1`'s hash code, `Computer A`'s hash code is needed and that includes its `processList` hashCode, which contains `Computer A` and so on. It's impossible to compute the hash code and the method will run until the current thread's stack overflows with local variables holding the partial results of the computation.

### Solution 1

If you don't need Lombok-generated `hashCode()`, `equals()` and `toString()`, then replace `@Data` with `@Getter` and `@Setter`.

### Solution 2

If you want all the code generated by `@Data` including `hashCode()`, `equals()` and `toString()`, then you must replace it with more annotations and exclude the `computer` and `processList` fields to break the loop:

```java
@PlanningEntity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, exclude = "computer")
public class CloudProcess {

    private int requiredCpuPower;
    private int requiredMemory;
    private int requiredNetworkBandwidth;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"computerRange"})
    private CloudComputer computer;
}

@PlanningEntity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = "processList")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, exclude = "processList")
public class CloudComputer {

    private int cpuPower;
    private int memory;
    private int networkBandwidth;
    private int cost;


    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "computer")
    private List<CloudProcess> processList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```